# Namenode not connecting in talend

Tags: hadoop, talend, protobuf-java

I'm creating a Hadoop cluster in Talend with a cloudera connection

I connected the cluster but when going through the second step which is connecting the name node I get his error

[Hadoop Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Wb2.png)

[service error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kjDg.png)

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/927uB.png)

I tried downloading `protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar` manually and I think it is causing the main problem